# XPATH SELENIUM=Cannot add variable

Tags: xpath

I am trying to add a variable to an xpath but to no avail

This works below for java
assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,'2 Employees selected')]"));

but when I add a variable , like below it does not

String CountEmp1="2";
assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,CountEmp1+'Employees selected')]"));

Comment: I think you just need to add a space, otherwise the expected value will be `2Employees selected`

Comment: If you could give an example of the markup and possible values by editing the question, that would really help. What I meant by my earlier comment was that you have a successful match with `2 Employees selected` whereas you want to parameterise the number part so you need to add the space between the number and the `Employees selected` part like this `CountEmp1+' Employees selected'` (note the space before the `E`). You are using [`contains`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) which will try to match the text exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put CountEmp1 as a string addition in the main verifyElePresent func i.e `verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,"+CountEmp1+"Employees selected')]"));`

Note the replacement of "+CountEmp1+" at contains(.,CountEmp1+'

With your xpath the verifyElementPresent method basically looks for //*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,CountEmp1+'Employees selected')] where countEmp1 is taken as string value and not something that needs to be concatenadated.

Comment: this found that it was a variable so thanks but still did not like it particular when concatenated with the string. I notice that the 'selected has no opening '. Could this be the problem

Comment: cannot anyone help a little further with this please

Comment: It might be the space that andyb is mentioning so it should be contains(.,"+CountEmp1+" Employees selected')]"..I didn't quite get the part of 'selected has no opening'

Comment: Hi, I am trying to subistute a string value with a variable namely the value 2

Comment: Here is the example assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,'2 Employees selected')]")); so I need to add a string variable to 2 for example String CountEmp=2;assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,"+CountEmp1+"Employees selected')]")); This worked below  but not really happy with it  assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,CountEmp)]"));
assertTrue("Failed", verifyElementPresent("//*[@class='StdLJText' and contains(.,'Employees selected')]"));